# How can I use If/else condition in React to display array of data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

In React component I have array of books, on click of `Hide Books` I set array of data to empty so nothing is displayed on page the change Button text to `Show Books`

What I am trying to achieve is When click on button with text `Show Books` I want to display data by setting `setBooksData(bookData)`

```
function BookList() {
  const [booksData, setBooksData] = useState(books);
  const clearBooks = () => {
    setBooksData([]);
  };
  return (
    <section className="booklist">
      {booksData.map((book, index) => {
        return <Book key={index} {...book}></Book>;
      })}
      <button onClick={clearBooks}>
        {booksData.length === 0 ? "Show Books" : "Hide Books"}
      </button>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a another state to hide and show the book list. In your code you have made booklist as empty, so that when you click on the show book, booklist will be empty.

Now here i have used another state to hide and show the books.
to show the book i have added two condition to check whether the book array has data and whether in show state.

```
function BookList() {
      const [booksData, setBooksData] = useState(books);
      const [hideBook,setHidden]=useState(false);
      const clearBooks = () => {
        setHidden(!hideBook)
      };
      
      return (
        <section className="booklist">
          {!hideBook && booksData.length >0 &&
          booksData.map((book, index) => {
            return <Book key={index} {...book}></Book>;
          })
          }
          <button onClick={clearBooks}>
            {hideBook ? "Show Books" : "Hide Books"}
          </button>
        </section>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Little complex to understand but I will try

Comment: We just using a another button to hide and show. We did not do anything to the book array thats all.

Comment: Okay, why do we set `!hideBook` and `setHidden(!hideBook)`

Comment: This answer is a much better pattern, I would suggest you go this route. Changing an array of many items just for a visibility toggle doesn't make sense. What @mithelan is doing here is using a toggler to either display or hide data, without mutating the data array itself. `setHidden(!hideBook)` is toggling the value of `hideBook` from true to false and then false to true (toggling). When that boolean changes, the code in the render checks if we're supposed to hide or show the books via this boolean (`hideBook`).

Comment: @JohnRuddell explained clearly.

Comment: in that case const [booksData, setBooksData] = useState(books); is not required as it not doing anythig, you can map directly as data is not manupulating in this component

Comment: @AnshukSharma yes for the current snippet, but that doesn't mean that the use case for the OP is exactly the code we see here. I could easily see a `BookList` component using filters, which would need to either create a new list of items or update the bookLists state variable to change. The point here is the pattern of how to implement a visibility toggle is much cleaner when you use a boolean to help represent that toggle. Let your code be explicit, instead of relying on implicit behavior to give the desired effect.

Comment: Yeah, totally agreed, code should follow the imutability, here it mapped, so would not required extra state to maintain, anyway state is use to mean for controlled component

Comment: @AnshukSharma To me having the state variable vs not having it is not all that important... But if you were going to properly fix this, what should probably change is the books should be props to the list component so it can be reused for other book lists on other pages as a future use case. And then not use local state at all for the list but rather state variables for things like filters and searching... etc. Then make a memoized list `const filteredBooks = useMemo` and only recalculate the list of items when a filter / search / books change. Then just use `filteredBooks` when rendering.

Comment: multiple state handling in a component difficult to handle, here is two so it fine, props, or selector always have a good pattern

Answer (score 0):

with you logic, you need to toggle the item, if it have list and clicking on hide it will hide otherwise it will reset

```
const BookLists = () => {
  const [bookLists, setBooksData] = useState(books);

  const toggleBookList = () => {
    if (!!bookLists.length) {
      setBooksData([]);

      return;
    }

    setBooksData(books);
  };

  return (
    <section className="booklist">
      <ul>
        {bookLists.map((book, index) => (
          <Book key={index} label={book} />
        ))}
      </ul>

      <button onClick={toggleBookList}>
        {bookLists.length === 0 ? 'Show Books' : 'Hide Books'}
      </button>
    </section>
  );
};

export { BookLists };
```

Comment: here, it the working demo, also you should not use index as key, please use id, or the name of the books  with index
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-34zpft?file=src%2FBookLists.js

Answer (score -1):

Since both buttons have different functionality, you can separate them, and assign each its own handler functions

```js
function BookList() {
  const [booksData, setBooksData] = useState(books);
  const clearBooks = () => {
    setBooksData([]);
  };

  const handleShowBook = () => {
    setBooksData(books);
  }

  return (
    <section className="booklist">
      {booksData.map((book, index) => {
        return <Book key={index} {...book}></Book>;
      })}
      {
        booksData.length === 0
        ? 
        (<button onClick={handleShowBook}>
          Show Books
        </button>)
        :
        (<button onClick={clearBooks}>
          Hide Books
        </button>)
      }
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I cannot use the above logic?

Comment: With your logic you are just conditionally rendering the text. The handler function `clearBooks` remains the same. What you also is need is different handler function for each different text.

Comment: I am getting this in console`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a descendant of <button>.`

Comment: Because you are using my code inside the button. What you need is to replace your `<button>...<button>` with my `{ booksData.... ...}` instead.

Comment: Show books is not working. I add ```const handleShowBook = () => {
    setBooksData(booksData);
  };```

Comment: You need to `setBooksData(books)` instead of `booksData`, because you are clearing the state with `clearBooks` function remember?

Comment: Ahh. My bad, sorry